# Using a custom property in CWebUser that is only present after login in Yii

Tags: yii

In Yii I am trying to create a link to your own profile in the navigation menu. This link is made up of your first and last name from the database and is only visible to logged in members. I can set these fine on login. But the problem I'm having that I don't know how to correct in Yii is what happens when a non-logged in member views the page.

Because currently it just errors and throws an:

Property "CWebUser.first_name" is not defined.

This is how my menu is set up

```
array(
        'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
        'size'=>'small',
        'type'=>'primary', // '', 'primary', 'info', 'success', 'warning', 'danger' or 'inverse'
        'buttons'=>array(
           array('visible'=> !Yii::app()->user->isGuest, 'label'=>Yii::app()->user->first_name .' '. Yii::app()->user->last_name, 'items'=>array(
           array('label'=>'Profile', 'url'=>array('/site/logout')),
           array('label'=>'Settings', 'url'=>array('/site/something')),
           '---',
           array('label'=>'Logout', 'url'=>array('/site/somethingElse')),
        )))
    ),
```

I understand the reason why it errors, but not how to correct this in Yii. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks

Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes for a bit ugly code but you could put this ternary operator in "label"

```
!Yii::app()->user->isGuest ? Yii::app()->user->first_name .' '. Yii::app()->user->last_name : '';
```

Which basically works like this

```
boolean_stateent ? if_true_then_this_value : else_use_this_value;
```

So it checks if the user is not a guest (aka is logged in), and then prints the first + last name. If the user is a guest, it doesn't bother to try to access first_name and last_name, so no error will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks, I went for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your custom `WebUser` class (if you haven't yet: Just extend it from `CWebUser` and configure it as your `user` component). Then you can use a getter for the user name:

```
public function getFullName()
{
    return $this->getIsGuest() ? '' : $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
}
```

In your menu you then use `Yii::app()->user->fullName`. It will be empty for guest users.